# javascript to copy text from textbox to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple textbox:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="height: 100px; width: 500px" value=""></input>
```

Now I need to copy text, which was entered to textbox to div which will be after textbox. Maybe you could say, how can I do it? There can be submit button or text could be copied automatically and text box would disappear.

Comment: `input` is self-closing.

Answer (score 2):

use [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) in JQquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(){   //triggers when keyup in textbox
         var txtBoxVal =$(this).val();
        $('#textVal').text(txtBoxVal);   //assigns value to your div
    });   
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/pYuKt/)**

add `$(this).hide('slow');`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/pYuKt/1/) for hide of text box, (i'm not sure about your implementation with this)

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
var cache = $('#textbox');
cache.next('div').text(cache.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

**Jquery:**

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function(){
    $('#content').text($('#textbox').val());

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="textbox" type="text"/>
<div id="content"></div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m76qY/)

Answer (score 0):

Say that you have added a button with `id="submit"`, then you could achieve this with the following way:

```
$('#submit').onClick(function(){
    var text = $("#textbox").val();
    $("#textbox").hide();
    $('#divId').html(text);
});
```

The `divId` is the id of the div, in which you want to append the text that entered in the textbox.

Comment: An `input` field doesn't have `.text()`. It should be `.val()`.

Comment: @putvande sorry, I haven't forgotten it. I will change it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inline solution (uses jquery)

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="height: 100px; width: 500px" value="" onchange="javascript:$(this).next('div').text($(this).val())" />
```

you can use the same on the onkeypress instead of onchange to apply text to div immediately.